# Simplifying Boolean Expression

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, digital-circuits, karnaugh-map

I am designing a 4-bit comparator with a look ahead unit using a bit slice approach. I have to break the propagation of the Logical expressions for `(A<B)i` and `(A>B)i`. The main question is, could I use the following to simplify the boolean expressions.. The i is a subscript meaning the ith bit. The i-1 is a subscript meaning the bit before the ith bit.

`(A<B)i = ~Ai*Bi + ~Ai*(A<B)i-1 + Bi*(A<B)i-1`

Could I Take `~Ai` common from the first two expressions leaving me with

`~Ai*(Bi + (A<B)i-1) + Bi(A<B)i-1`

Let's call  `Bi + (A<B)i-1) = Q`

And let's call `~Ai = P`

I'm left with `P*Q + Q`

Using the boolean law that `Q + Q*P = Q`

Can I simplify the expression to just

`(A<B)i = Bi + (A<B)i-1`

Comment: I would have preferred a simpler notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot simplify to $(A<B)_i = B_i + (A<B)_{i-1}$, Take for example $A=11$ and $B = 10$.

Then $(A<B)_2$ = False, $B_2$ = True, and $(A<B)_1$ = False. If you substitute the values above then the equation is not satisfied. The original equation(s) is correct.

$(A<B)_i = \neg A_i B_i + (\neg A_i+B_i)(A<B)_{i-1}$
$(A<B)_1 = \neg A_1 B_1$

In your derivation of simpler formula, $B_i + (A<B)_{i-1} = Q$ but you are incorrectly substituting $B_i (A<B)_{i-1} = Q$ in rightmost term.